# Using UIView as containers

Tags: iphone

I am making a universal app. And even though I set the autoresizing masks on some of the components I need to "group" them. I want each group to be proportionally repositioned, but not each component. Is it bad or are other ways than add them to invisible UIView's so I can group them.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would say you could create a grouped control :) or something similar. Then you can add all your subviews as you suggested to this grouped control, then you resize this group control ... 
I believe there is nothing wrong with this solution, unless you do not overuse it, and say add 100 grouped views ... that's a bit of an overhead, and i would choose another solution.

However if you add only of couple of them i would go for it ...

Comment: Thank you, yes there are only 6 "groups" so I will do that.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is spot-on. It's a best practice as far as I'm aware, and empty views are cheap (in the sense there's no extra memory used for the container view's layer).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not bad.  If they behave the way you want them to and don't leak or cause performance problems, go for it.